# IIS7 Diagnostics and Tracing is showing up at the bottom of my aspx page. How do I turn it off?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I know I must have turned something on either in IIS7, in my Web.Config or heck even IE9 for all I know. I am seeing a gargantuan amount of diagnostics and tracing at the bottom of one of ASPX pages for a specific site I am working on at work and I have no idea how to turn it off.

Can anyone tell me how to turn this off if they know what I am talking about?

Here is a picture:

[image: Diagnostics and Tracing Information]

I apologize for the size, but the diagnostics printed out are huge and that is only some of the miles of diagnostics printed out. It is handy and all, but I don't want to see it anymore.

The topics printed out are:

- Request Details
- Trace Information
- Control Tree
- Session State
- Application State
- Request Cookies Collection
- Response Cookies Collection
- Headers Collection
- Response Headers Collection
- Form Collection
- Querystring Collection
- Server Variables

I searched for this on google and on this site, but I don't know how to phrase what I am looking at any better than I have already into a question. So I apologize if this is a duplicate post or if it has been answered already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My website has been doing this for many months. I've tried asking before, but no one was able to understand what I was asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this in the `web.config` file under the `system.web` section:

```
<trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true"/>
```

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes to mark that as the correct answer, but yes that did it. I got confused because I was changing some setting in IIS7 and I work with different copies of the same Web.Config so it wasn't happening for all of my branches. That is why I thought it might be a IIS7 deal. That fixed it though, thanks a lot.